# Swift MeasurementFormatter get string without symbol

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to calculate pace of runner and I use that code

```
static func pace(distance: Measurement<UnitLength>, seconds: Int, outputUnit: UnitSpeed) -> String {
  let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
  formatter.unitOptions = [.providedUnit]
  let speedMagnitude = seconds != 0 ? distance.value / Double(seconds) : 0
  let speed = Measurement(value: speedMagnitude, unit: UnitSpeed.metersPerSecond)
  let avgPace = formatter.string(from: speed.converted(to: outputUnit))

  return avgPace.replacingOccurrences(of: " min/km", with: "")
}
```

And I have extension for UnitSpeed

```
extension UnitSpeed {
  class var minutesPerKilometer: UnitSpeed {
      return UnitSpeed(symbol: "min/km", converter: UnitConverterPace(coefficient: 60.0 / 1000.0))
  }

  class var minutesPerMile: UnitSpeed {
      return UnitSpeed(symbol: "min/mi", converter: UnitConverterPace(coefficient: 60.0 / 1609.34))
  }
}
```

I don't like these lines:

`let avgPace = formatter.string(from: speed.converted(to: outputUnit))`

`return avgPace.replacingOccurrences(of: " min/km", with: "")`

Question is how to get clean value from `formatter` without replacingOccurrences?

Comment: Just take the `speed.value`, it's a unit-less `Double` value.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You meant `speed.converted(to: outputUnit).value`

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah, I didn't noticed it wasn't converted yet. But yes

Comment: Thank you! `speed.converted(to: outputUnit).value` works good